Vuejs uppercase custom directive not working
I've built the following directive to transform an input's v-model into uppercase:
app.directive('uppercase', (el) => {
  el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
})

But when I apply it, the resulting v-model returns the input value with the last character in lowercase.
  <template>
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-uppercase v-model="testInput" />
      <div>
        {{ testInput }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
    
  <script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    const testInput = ref('')
  </script>

Why is this not working?

This isn't a good use for a directive because it's model value that is supposed to be the source of truth, not input value.
Even if it's possible to work around input value updates, as another answer shows, the mentioned problem would reveal because the directive won't affect initial model value; the input wasn't touched.
A more straightforward approach is to address it from the side of a model:
const testInput = ref('');

watchEffect(
  () => { testInput.value = testInput.value.toUpperCase(); },
  { flush: 'sync' },
);

v-model modifiers are intended for this kind of modified behaviour. As shown in the documentation, custom component can implement a modifier similar to uppercase transform.

Right, but I need the model to change to uppercase as well, not just the visual input

This is exactly what code does.

Got it. Thanks!

Faced with a similar one. Not sure if this is the right solution, but I called the input event to work correctly:
app.directive('uppercase', el => {
  el.value = el.value.toUpperCase();
  el.addEventListener('input', ($event: Event) => {
    if ($event.isTrusted) {
      el.value = el.value.toUpperCase();
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    }
  });
});


This won't affect initial value, it needs to be additionally handled on mount
